# Problem in installing package

Tags: packages, miktex-update

I have installed new window 7 and using latest version of  Latex and MIKTEX. The problem is that when I try to install package from MIKTEX so I get the error "Couldn't resolve host name". I have an important file which is ready in latex but due to this issue I am facing a lot of trouble. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe there's a problem with a repository? Did you try to install from another one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem  after installation of new Windows 7 is solved now here are some procedures that I followed to solve this problem:

1. As I had older version of MIKTEK so I uninstalled it completely.
2. Removed file Miktex from (c:\program files\miktex) and during this process system may give you error of program running in background so press ctrl+alt+delete and go to processes and press endtast for MIKTEX from there and again go to c:\program files\miktex and remove MIKTEX file.
3. After step 2 I installed latest version of MIKTEX from https://miktex.org
4. Then I go to start---All programs--- MIKTEX2.9----Maintainance (Admin)------MIKTEX Package Manager(Admin)-----Edit-----Select installable packages----then pressed + to install all packages.
5. For new windows 7 when I tried to open new file from Texmaker so I got this ----"The procedure entry point urctbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-1-1-0.dll"----error which was solved by installing C++ file named (vc_redist.x64.exe)  from (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).
6. After installation of C++ file  Texmaker is working perfectly.

Comment: In general, if you uninstall MikTeX, be sure to remove C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Miktex as well, so that the new install is clean. I recommend using the portable version of MikTeX, which avoids a few problems seen with admin installations.